# How to validate Pandas Dataframe column consist of month-end dates?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, series

I have a Pandas DF that has a column called `ref_date` which consists of dates. I want to verify that all the dates are the last day of the month. I'm trying to do it this way, but it doesn't seem to give me the correct results, particularly the `df[ref_date].dt.is_month_end` part is not giving me a correct Series.

```
df[ref_date] = pd.to_datetime(df[ref_date])

month_end_dates = df[ref_date].dt.is_month_end

indices = np.where(month_end_dates == False)[0]

if indices.size > 0:
    idx = indices[0]
    raise ValidationError("The following date is not the end of a month: " + str(df[ref_date][idx].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
```

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is an example:

df (when outputted):

```
    ref_date      regime_tag
0  2010-01-31           3
1  2010-02-28           2
2  2010-03-31           1
3  2010-04-30           2
4  2010-05-31           1
5  2010-06-30           1
6  2010-07-31           4
7  2010-08-31           1
8  2010-09-30           2
9  2010-10-29           4
10 2010-11-30           3
11 2010-12-31           3
```

month_end_dates (when outputted):

```
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
```

This is not right because 31 Jan 2010 is a month end and 29 Oct 2010 is not.

**ANSWER:**

```
    month_end_dates = df.ref_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) == df.ref_date

indices = np.where(month_end_dates == False)[0]

if indices.size > 0:
    idx = indices[0]
    raise ValidationError("The following date is not the end of a month: " + str(df[ref_date][idx].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')))
```

Comment: can you give some lines as examples from your dataframe please ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you please explain why you believe that this does not work. Or better yet, give a sample or expected and actual output.

Comment: I added an output snippet into the question.

Comment: Running your code, I get the correct result with the only `False` at index 9. Perhaps your original data set has special characters so that the `to_datetime()` conversion fails to produce the correct results?

Comment: To reemphasize in case someone comes across this later: I believe the original code (before the answer was included in the question) is 100% correct and should give the correct result under normal circumstances.

Comment: use [`Series.dt.is_month_end`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.is_month_end.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.offsets.MonthEnd`

```
df.ref_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) == df.ref_date

0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
Name: ref_date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose

```
df.ref_date.apply(lambda x: True if x.is_month_end else False)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As written this is a low quality answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to improve your post.